# Magento 2 send data from Login to Registration

Tags: php, authentication, registration, magento2

How can I send the login data (like email) to create account form?
I tried this but not worked:

```
$data = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer');
$data->setData('form_data', ['email' => $login['username']]);
$data->setData('email', $login['username']);
```

And this:

```
$item = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register');
$item->setData('form_data', ['email' => $resp->username]);
$item->setData('email', $resp->username);
```

I put this code into {mymodule}\Controller\Account\LoginPost.php execute method.
I'd like to set the default value on registration form by the login email.

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I put this into my own LoginPost.php

```
$this->session->setCustomerFormData($data);
```

Where $data is array.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the template file of any registration form then you can directly print the value in input text field.

If it is still not working, share the screenshot if it is possible.